# convert foreign field objectid to string in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate, lookup, objectid

Here I'm joining two collection with using $lookup. please help me to fix this

```
Product.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup: {
          from: "product_categories",
          localField: "category_id",
          foreignField: "_id", <== i'm unable access this
          as: "category"
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: You may have a look at the answer for [MongoDB aggregation matching ObjectId against string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70954804/mongodb-aggregation-matching-objectid-against-string). The concept is similar.

Comment: hey, thanks for the suggestion. The link you've provided is not related to my question, i wanted to conver foreignField OjbectId into string so i can category data with product

Comment: What you need: 1. $lookup with `let`, `pipeline`. 2. Convert the ObjectId value to string with [`$toString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/).

Comment: Converting the foreign objectid to string will require examining every document in the from collection every time this aggregation runs.  Have you considered changed the local field to objectid instead?